# Laravel 5.5 file extension validation not working

Tags: validation, laravel-5

**Requirement**: User can only upload pdf, word document, excel or powerpoint. 
I have tried these validations rules and none of them are working:

```
'fileUpload' => 'sometimes|mimes:doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pdf,zip|max:2048',
```

I have also tried below rules to test pdf.

```
'fileUpload' => 'sometimes|mimetypes:application/pdf|max:2048',
'fileUpload' =>  'sometimes|mimetypes:pdf|max:2048',
'fileUpload' =>  'sometimes|mimes:application/pdf|max:2048',
'fileUpload' =>  'sometimes|mimes:pdf|max:2048',
```

When I try to upload any file then first rule says:

```
The file upload must be a file of type: doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pdf, zip.
```

And second rule says:

```
The file upload must be a file of type: application/pdf.
```

I had also tried to change rules arrangements but still same issue.

I am manually handling this requirement. But want to know why these validation rules are not working.

Comment: Where are you getting the `sometimes` rule from?

Comment: @afraz some binary files get their mime types recognized incorrectly as `binary/octet-stream` instead of their actual type. You can call `guessExtension()` function on the instance of UploadedFile to see what mime type Laravel things the file is.

Comment: I have tried to check mime types with 

    $file->getMimeType(); and those are correct. Means when I upload pdf then it says application/pdf. and guessExtension() is also returning pdf.

Comment: @btl sometimes is a rule provided by laravel to validate input if available.

Comment: Oh interesting, I wasn't aware of that one. Looks very useful.

Comment: Be sure, the file is not empty, I lost 4 hours trying with an empty file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I was trying to upload multiple files and validation rule was expected to validate array like this

```
'fileUpload.*'. instead of just 'fileUpload'
```

I was just missing the  * . 
Because my input field is uploading multiple files

```
<input  type="file" name="fileUpload[]" multiple />
```

Answer (score 1):

As per 5.5 [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimetypes)

Basic Usage Of MIME Rule

```
'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```

> Even though you only need to specify the extensions, this rule
>   actually validates against the MIME type of the file by reading the
>   file's contents and guessing its MIME type.

A full listing of MIME types and their corresponding extensions may be found at the following location: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Just try with full extensions once

```
'fileUpload' => 'sometimes|mimes:application/pdf|max:2048',
```